# How to restore Acronis True Image 2014 backup to another HDD

Tags: backup, acronis-trueimage

In earlier versions of Acronis True Image, there was a function in "Restore" section: Select .TIB file to restore **and select destination device/partition**. But I can't figure out how to restore (for ex.) mybackup.tib file to my external HDD. Is this function removed from version 2014 ? 
Bulid 5560. 
 Sync Agent Version 17.0.0.1646 
 OS: Windows 8.1 x64

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Acronis-True-Image-Backup-Recovery/product-reviews/B00EFRMDW2